# Determine if any Wednesday 3pm is contained in an Interval?

Tags: jodatime

The question is pretty self-explanatory. I'd like to create a new Interval(then, now) and see if any Wednesday at 3pm (or any other day of week/time combination) is contained within that interval. To be clear, I'm not interested in whether a specific DateTime is contained in the Interval, but just a generic day of week/time combo.

Is there an elegant/clean way to do this in Joda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   DateTime fromDate = new DateTime(); // begin interval
   DateTime toDate = fromDate.plusMinutes(999999); // end inteval
   Interval interval = new Interval(fromDate, toDate); // interval
   DateTime anchor = fromDate.minusWeeks(1).withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.WEDNESDAY).withMillisOfDay(
      0).withHourOfDay(15); // Wednesday 3pm from previous week

   while (anchor.isBefore(toDate))
   {
      if (interval.contains(anchor))
      {
         return anchor; // if interval contains Wednesday 3pm - > return it
      }
      else
      {
         anchor = anchor.plusWeeks(1); // else get next Wednesday 3pm from next week  
      }
   }
   return null; // Wednesday 3pm isn't in interval
```